# onEditActionListener android defined

Tags: java, android

I have been getting into the android app world as of late. I understand that you want to place what variables you can into the `onCreate` method so that you can start using your variables right away. However, I am at a loss for a part of my code where I need to define onEditActionListener's to listen for user input but then also once enter is pressed get their text and send it to another activity. My research has shown I want to define these using the `EditText` and onEditActionListeners. however, I am at a loss as to how to go about this. Do I need to create a class that extends `onEditActionListener`?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horde_calculator);
        EditText myText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numToSend);
        OnEditorActionListener onEditorActionListener = new myClass();
        myText.setOnEditorActionListener(onEditorActionListener);
}
```

that is a copy of my current code and I am unsure if this is the correct way to go about doing it. If I was to create a new `onEditActionListener` wouldn't that make my `onCreate` more complex than having a few lines of variables? I feel that there might be a more clear way of going about this. However, after looking through stack overflow I couldnt' seem to find something that made sense. I didn't want to just copy and paste code, but really understand how it all flows together.

Comment: @zombie if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, daysRemaining.class);
            String message = textBox.getText().toString();
            int userInput = Integer.parseInt(message);
            myIntent.putExtra(testMessage, userInput);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            Log.d("onEditorAction", view.getText().toString());
            Log.d("onEditorAction", textBox.getText().toString());
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another idea of how you can achieve this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {

    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numToSend);
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
                && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            //both attempt are the same
            Log.d("onEditorAction", view.getText().toString());
            Log.d("onEditorAction", editText.getText().toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question. If I was attempting to also get the value from the user input into that textview field would i put that underneath the onEditorAction area? Something like editText.getText().toString()? Or would i be unable to use editText since it is defined in the protected class?

Comment: Thanks alot! :D You have helped me tremendously :D

Comment: Hey, i was also attempting to actually grab the text from the editText listener that the user inputted. How do i go about doing this ? I know how to generate a new activity. Here is what i was attempting :  Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, daysRemaining.class);
            String message = textBox.getText().toString();
            myIntent.putExtra(testMessage, message);
            startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: check the build intent section in https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I did look there and attempt to study the code itself. However, I am still a bit confused. Do i need to declare another edittext and set it equal to the same view as i did in teh oncreate when i created my listener?

Comment: No I don't think you should do that but still can't be sure without looking at your final code at the moment

Comment: By the way asking another question is totally free and you might reach more people you can also tag me in there so I would try to help

Comment: Ah ok would i do that by answering my own question down below? Or create a new question like i crewated this one?

Comment: Add a comment with @ zombie without the space below the question or add the link here

Comment: if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, daysRemaining.class);
            String message = textBox.getText().toString();
            int userInput = Integer.parseInt(message);
            myIntent.putExtra(testMessage, userInput);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            Log.d("onEditorAction", view.getText().toString());
            Log.d("onEditorAction", textBox.getText().toString());
        }

Comment: @user3258385 this is not the way stackoverflow works please add it as another answer

Answer (score 0):

Use TextView.OnEditorActionListener :

```
TextView.OnEditorActionListener listener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

           if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL  
               && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 

     //call your new activity here

            }
           return true;
        }
    };

myText.setOnEditorActionListener(listener);
```